# Swift 2.0 Reflection on Metatype

Tags: ios, reflection, swift2

Swift reflection works great on an instance of a particular type but what if I want to print out all the instance variables of a particular class?

Creating a `Mirror` works for an instance:

```
Mirror(reflecting: self).children.filter { $0.label != nil }.map { return $0.label! }
```

but when self is a class like `Bird` or `Fruit`, the list returned is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue where my own custom classes were returning no children when I created a mirror of them. Try using `superclassMirror()` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33740180/1478580). It's what solved my problem...

For example:

```
let myMirror = Mirror(reflecting: self).superclassMirror()
myMirror.children.filter { $0.label != nil }.map { return $0.label! }
```